# UITableView isn't working

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

Im trying to make a comments UITableView inside a UIViewController but I'm having problems. If I set the text directly, it shows up (cell.username.text) but if I try to fill it with a PFQuery (parse.com) nothing shows up

```
    //DetailViewController.h    
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Parse/Parse.h>

    @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController{

    }

    @property (strong, nonatomic) PFObject *place;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *userPhoto;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *username;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *message;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distance;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *checkCount;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *photo;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *commentsTableView;

    - (IBAction)checkMarkButton:(UIButton *)sender;


    @end

//DetailViewController.m
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "CommentsViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController (){

    CommentsViewController *test;
}

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize place;
@synthesize userPhoto, message, username, checkCount, photo, scroller, commentsTableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    test = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];
    self.commentsTableView.delegate = test;
    self.commentsTableView.dataSource = test;

    [test commentsQuery:place];
}

//CommentsViewController.h
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface CommentsViewController : UITableViewController{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) PFObject *place;

- (void)commentsQuery:(PFObject *)object;

@end

//CommentsViewController.m
#import "CommentsViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "CommentsCell.h"

@interface CommentsViewController (){
    NSArray *commentsArray;
}



@end

@implementation CommentsViewController

@synthesize place;



- (void)commentsQuery:(PFObject *)object {

    place = object;

    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activity"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"comment"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"place" equalTo:place];
    [query1 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            commentsArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[commentsArray count]);
        }
    }];

}






-  (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [commentsArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CommentsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CommentsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *tempObj = [commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.username.text = @"username";
    cell.comment.text = [tempObj objectForKey:@"content"];
    cell.userThumbnail.file = [tempObj objectForKey:@"userThumbnail"];
    [cell.userThumbnail loadInBackground];



    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you make sure that what you're getting from the dictionary isn't null? Maybe you can NSLog it and update your post with the result?

Comment: I think you mix <commentsTableView> UITableView IBOutlet (in fact that displayed) then 
your custom <CommentsViewController> subclass of UITableViewController

Comment: @Mr_bem your right, the commentsQuery is coming up null in the table but it works fine if i put the nslog in the actual query. My only guess is that I have to refresh the table because it is called before the query is finished but how do I refresh the table because I dont have access to [reloadData] since IBOutlet UITableView *commentsTableView is in the DetailViewController?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was calling reloadData. I followed the answer here and it works [UITableView delegate and datasource in a separate class after parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407844/uitableview-delegate-and-datasource-in-a-separate-class-after-parsing)